# populate drop-down list with column headings from sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box where an arbitrary SQL SELECT statement can be entered.  I want to generate a table displaying the results and a chart as well with a drop-down list for both the y and x axis where the user can select which result column to display on the x-axis and which to display on the y-axis.

Presently, I use the text in the text box to update the SelectCommand for a SqlDataSource.  I have a GridView tied to the data source with AutoGenerateColumns set to true.  This generates my table well.

I have the chart tied to the same data source and I would like to populate two drop-down lists to the results column headers, and then update the XValueMember & XValueMember attributes for the chart.  The problem I'm having is how to determine the column names in order to populate the drop-down lists.  Since the GridView generates these automatically, I tried to read from there, but I get the old values, not the ones from the most recent SELECT statement.

In my default.aspx I have:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlX" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlX_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlY" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlY_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>'</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and in the code-behind (C#)

```
protected void ddlX_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = this.ddlX.SelectedValue;
}
protected void ddlY_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = this.ddlY.SelectedValue;
}
```

But how to populate drop-down box.

Comment: What have you tried? Add some code to your question and tell us where you are having the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a working solution: read gridview columns during page_load and update chart XSeries and YSeries.  Code now looks like:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlX" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlY" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>'</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get column names from gridview and populate ddl
    int cols = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;
    int selInd = ddlX.SelectedIndex;
    ddlX.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        LinkButton Link = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        string col = Link.Text;
        ddlX.Items.Insert(i, col);
    }
    ddlX.SelectedIndex = selInd;
    cols = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;
    selInd = ddlY.SelectedIndex;
    ddlY.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        LinkButton Link = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        string col = Link.Text;
        ddlY.Items.Insert(i, col);
    }
    ddlY.SelectedIndex = selInd;
    // set chart axes
    Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = ddlX.SelectedValue;
    Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = ddlY.SelectedValue;

}
```